# Probability union of events

Tags: probability

I am stuck at with this equation:
Given that $A, B, C$ are arbitary events. 
I need to proove that $P(A ∪ B ∪ C) \le P(A) + P(B) + P(C)$.
I use the $P(A ∪ B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B)$
So I get $P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(B ∩ C) - P(A ∩(B ∩ C)$ I am stuck here I don't know how to proceed. I looked through many threads but people seem to stop here and don't take it any further.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Answer (score 3):

$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$ is the rule we have; however, we want a union of three events! Like you suggest, the right way of expanding a rule for two things to a rule for three things is to group things together: Consider $A \cup B \cup C$ not as a union of $A, B, C,$ but instead as a union of $A$ and $B\cup C.$ Then, we get
$$P(A \cup (B \cup C)) = P(A) + P(B\cup C) - P(A \cap (B \cup C)).$$

Now, we expand again to get rid of $P(B\cup C),$ finding that
$$P(A\cup B \cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(B \cap C) - P(A \cap (B\cup C)).$$

The inequality then follows as probabilities are non-negative.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what do you mean by "The inequality then follows as probabilities are non-negative"? 
P. S. nevermind, i get what you mean

Comment: @LetMeLearn subtracting positive numbers from an entity is only going to make it smaller... $x-z \le x$ if $z \ge 0$.

Comment: @LetMeLearn probabilities are non negative, so the left hand side can at most be the P(a) + P(b) + P(c) .